# Unity3D: Do Unity's NavMeshAgents no longer push lower priority agents out of the way?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, navmesh

I've recently come across a slight issue with Unity's agents. Up until now, our Agents would be pushed out of the way if they intersected another (higher or equal priority) agent.

However recently that behaviour has changed and they just intersect/pass through each other now. The lower priority agent seems to disable (remains stationary) until the higher priority agent has moved away.

Is there an underlying issue to do with my AI (is this a problem my end), or was this a change made to the NMAs by Unity?

I am using Unity 2018.2.10f1

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else gets a similar issue, for me it was caused by not having the Agent set to UpdatePosition. Turning this back to true fixed the intersecting behaviour.